# Importing modules fails in Codeship

Tags: python, continuous-integration, python-import, importerror, codeship

I have a repository with the following directory structure:

```
repo_folder\
----src\
    ----__init__.py
    ----src1.py
    ----src2.py
    ----src3.py
----testing\
    ----specific_test.py
----requirements.txt
```

---

`specific_test.py` has on it's first lines:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))
import src.src1
import src.src2
import src.src3

# lots of asserts
```

---

When I run `specific_test.py` from within `testing` folder or from `repo_folder` folder it works, but **only** on my **local machine.**

The problem is that when I try to run this from my `codeship` account, it gives me an `Import Error`.
The error looks like this:

- `ImportError` while importing test module
- ERROR collecting `testing/specific_test.py`
- No module named `src.src1`
- Make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.

---

Do you know what would the problem be?

Do you have suggestions for better alternatives?

Comment: I did include an __ init __.py file in the testing folder. For the moment it gives me another error which refers to an invalid syntax on some imported module.Judging from this I think it works .. I'm still verifying. The syntax error must come from the fact that codeship deploys a python2.7 environment instead of python3.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a pathing issue.  What seems to be happening on your local machine is you insert into your path your CWD, which is most likely returning as `repo_folder\`. from there, you can import your src files via `src.src1` because src is containe.  On your codeship account, the cwd (current working directory) is not correct, thus is cannot find the `src.` part of `src.src1`.  Check what the line `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))` returns, more importantly `os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())` and verify that it is leading to `repo_folder\`